# iBatis parameter - MaximumCheckoutTime

Tags: java, config, ibatis

Does anyone have any idea about this config parameter in iBatis sqlMapConfig.xml file?

`MaximumCheckoutTime`

```
   <property name="Pool.MaximumCheckoutTime" value="150000"/>
```

I guess I am having hard time finding the info on this. I would like to know what all the parameters I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are asking for connection from pool and there is no inactive connections ibatis check for connections which are active for more time than `Pool.MaximumCheckoutTime`. If there is such connections it will get it, roll it back, create a new connection on its place and return it to you. If there is no connections that are active more time than `Pool.MaximumCheckoutTime`, pool will wait.

Answer (score 0):

the ibatis documentation has this description:

```
the maximum time a connection can be used before it *may* be given away again.
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what it means by `it *may* be given away again`?